# Background image Jpanels

Tags: java, jpanel

How do I add a background image I want to replace the greyish background with a image in a easy way to my code, I have tried multiple ways but I cant get it to work. Here is my code its a bit messy now and its only the GUI.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class GUI{
    private JFrame tFrame;
    private JLabel l_name, l_ingrediens1, l_ingrediens2, l_typ, l_tid, l_bild, l_logo, l_matbild, l_background;
    private JTextField tf_name;
    private JTextArea ta_recept1;
    private JList jl_list;
    private JPanel background, background1, backgroundBild, topp, logga, mitt, matbild;
    private JComboBox cb_ingrediens1, cb_ingrediens2, cb_typ, cb_tid;
    private JButton b_find, b_add, b_delete;
    private Receptbas mat;
    private Recept find;

    String[] basIngrediensStrings = { "Fläsk", "Kyckling", "Fisk", "Nöt", "Korv" };
    String[] typStrings = { "Förrätt", "Varmrätt", "Efterrätt", "Övrigt" };
    String[] tidStrings = { "10min", "20min", "30min", "40min", "50min", "60min", "70min", "80min" };
    ImageIcon loggo = new ImageIcon("logga.png");
    ImageIcon bild = new ImageIcon("bild.jpg");
    ImageIcon i_background = new ImageIcon("background.png");

    public GUI(Receptbas mat){
        this.mat = mat;

        tFrame = new JFrame("Recept");
        tFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        l_name = new JLabel("Namn");
        l_ingrediens1 = new JLabel("Ingrediens");
        l_ingrediens2 = new JLabel("Ingrediens");
        l_typ = new JLabel("Typ");
        l_tid = new JLabel("Tid");
        l_logo = new JLabel(loggo);
        l_matbild = new JLabel(bild);
        l_background = new JLabel(i_background);
        tf_name = new JTextField(12);
        ta_recept1 = new JTextArea(40, 10);
        /*jl_list = new JList(<String>[name](mat));
        */
        backgroundBild = new JPanel();
        background1 = new JPanel();
        background = new JPanel();
        topp = new JPanel();
        mitt = new JPanel();
        logga = new JPanel();
        matbild = new JPanel();

        tFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        background1.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(background1));
        background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mitt.setLayout(new BorderLayout(20,20));
        logga.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        topp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        matbild.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        b_add = new JButton("Skapa");
        b_delete = new JButton("Ta Bort");
        b_find = new JButton("Sök");
        cb_ingrediens1 = new JComboBox(basIngrediensStrings);
        cb_ingrediens2 = new JComboBox(basIngrediensStrings);
        cb_typ = new JComboBox(typStrings);
        cb_tid = new JComboBox(tidStrings);
        /*MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(background);*/

        b_delete.addActionListener(new Deleter());
        b_add.addActionListener(new Creater());
        b_find.addActionListener(new Finder());

        tFrame.add(background1);
        background1.add(background);
        background1.add(backgroundBild);
        background.add(logga, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        background.add(topp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        background.add(mitt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        topp.add(l_name);
        topp.add(tf_name);
        topp.add(l_ingrediens1);
        topp.add(cb_ingrediens1);
        topp.add(l_ingrediens2);
        topp.add(cb_ingrediens2);
        topp.add(l_typ);
        topp.add(cb_typ);
        topp.add(l_tid);                
        topp.add(cb_tid);
        topp.add(b_find);
        topp.add(b_add);
        mitt.add(ta_recept1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mitt.add(matbild, BorderLayout.WEST);
        backgroundBild.add(l_background);
        /*mitt.add(jl_list, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mt.addImage(i_background, 0);*/
        matbild.add(l_matbild);
        logga.add(l_logo);

        background.setOpaque(true);
        tFrame.pack();
        tFrame.setVisible(true);


    }

    /*protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int imwidth = i_background.getWidth(null);
        int imheight = i_background.getHeight(null);
        g.drawImage(l_background, 1, 1, null);
    }*/



    public class Finder implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            String name = tf_name.getText(); 
            find = mat.receptFind(name);
            String recept1 = find.getRecept1();
            String ingrediens1 = find.getIngrediens1();
            String ingrediens2 = find.getIngrediens2();
            String typ = find.getTyp();
            String tid = find.getTid();
            cb_ingrediens1.setSelectedItem(ingrediens1);
            cb_ingrediens2.setSelectedItem(ingrediens2);
            cb_typ.setSelectedItem(typ);
            cb_tid.setSelectedItem(tid);
            ta_recept1.setText(recept1);

        }

    }

    public class Deleter implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            mat.delete(find.getName()); 
            tf_name.setText(""); 


            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("save.srz");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                out.writeObject(mat);

                Integer lastInt = new Integer(Unique.last());
                out.writeObject(lastInt);
                out.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Creater implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

            Recept s1 = new Recept(tf_name.getText(), (String)cb_ingrediens1.getSelectedItem(), (String)cb_ingrediens2.getSelectedItem(), (String)cb_typ.getSelectedItem(), (String)cb_tid.getSelectedItem(), ta_recept1.getText());
            mat.add(s1);

            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("save.srz");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                out.writeObject(mat);
                Integer lastInt = new Integer(Unique.last());
                out.writeObject(lastInt);
                out.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add ImageIcon to the Jpanel should work.
You did :

```
ImageIcon loggo = new ImageIcon("logga.png");
l_logo = new JLabel(loggo);
logga.add(l_logo);
```

Seems that your JPanels haven't been set to visible (nor logga, nor l_logo)

Try also to explicitly set the size of JLabel and JPanel containg it.

Comment: @Fabian: so what exactly is not working? what do you see and what you don't?

Comment: The logo is working and is showing at the top the problem is the backgroundBild ( sorry for mixing english and swedish code ) I want it to replace the greyish background that is now. I have set the whole frame to be visible so all panels inside will be visible to.

Comment: @Fabian: have you tried of explicitly set the size of your JPanel or the JLabel inside it? maybe it's correct but has zero size

Comment: Might work ill try that. Im having lunch now but ill check it out in 10mins

Comment: Nope that didnt do it, it did make the gui abit more clean tho.

Comment: @Fabian: so let me understand. Do you see the backgroundBild panel but not the JLabel with the image inside it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the code from 0verbose about adding the image to the panel, try then calling a paint() or repaint() on the panel.
Something like logga.paint() or logga.repaint().